# Drupal console alternative for drush make on Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drush

I am trying to set up a way to download and install Drupal 8 with some custom modules and a profile, all from the command line.

For Drupal 7 i had written a drush make file that downloaded a list of modules, including a custom profile and several custom modules from local git repositories

Is there a possibility to do this using drupal console? I know it can be done with composer as long as the dependencies are public

Comment: Why don't you just use drush again? It works great with D8 aswell.

Comment: I am unsure of the long time support for drush, seeing that lots of people recommend using drupal console for things we were using drush before (downloading/installing modules, clearing cache etc). I will probably use drush, but i wanted to know if there was another way of doing it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use [composer](https://getcomposer.org). Drupal console is not meant to manage dependencies.

Composer works with private dependency. The only requirement is the installation of SSH keys for a git client. See: https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#using-private-repositories

Look also at [the official documentation for using composer and drupal](https://www.drupal.org/node/2718229).